# Why doesn't basic_string::append (iter, iter) call std::copy?

Tags: c++, string, copy

I just figured out that in Visual Studio C++ 2010, `basic_string::append (iter, iter)` is, obviously, not implemented by making use of `std::copy`.

First question:

Now suppose I implement my own iterator type, together with an optimized overloading of `std::copy` for my iterator type in order to provide more efficient block-wise copying. Is there any way to get `basic_string::append` to make use of this optimization, apart from overloading `append` as well?

Is there any chance that `basic_string::append (iter, iter)` does not do character-wise copying?

Second question (as a starting point for my own implementation):

Is the following guaranteed to be valid?

```
std::string t ("JohnB");
std::string s;
s.reserve (10);
std::copy (t.begin (), t.end (), s.begin ());
s.push_back ('\0');
```

or should I better use a `back_inserter`? If I use a `back_inserter` -- how can I avoid character-wise copying?

Comment: To answer your second question: `reserve()` followed by `copy()` is definitely __not valid__. Print `s.size()` after the copy to see why.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: But `resize()` followed by `copy()` will work.

Comment: What about `resize` followed by `copy`?

Comment: Yes, `resize()` is the correct function. The crucial difference is that `capacity()` and `size()` are not the same concepts.

Comment: I know. It was, however, not clear to me what that means in connection with `copy`.

Comment: `copy()` would work if the destination was `back_inserter`. Your example, using `s.begin()` wouldn't change the container `size`.

Comment: You might find this post of mine relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327163/improving-efficiency-of-stdcopy-with-back-inserter-or-inserter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `std::basic_string<cT, ...>::append()` keeps delegating a few time before it eventually arrives at the overload (21.4.6.2 [string::append] paragraph 7):

> `basic_string& append(const charT* s, size_type n);`

At this point there is clearly none of the original iterators left. In case you wonder what happens to the input iterator you may have passed to `append()`, the got removed by the overload in paragraph 17 of the same paragraph which states:

> Effects: Equivalent to `append(basic_string(first, last))`.

at some intermediate state. If the standard library is implemented the way as it is literally stated by the standard there is clearly no call to `std::copy()`.

You wouldn't really be able to see your overloaded version of `std::copy()` anyway, though. What the library may do is the moral equivalent of

```
template <typename InIt>
std::basic_string<cT, ...>& std::basic_string<cT, ...>::append(InIt begin, InIt end) {
    if (is_forward_iterator<begin>::value) {
        this->reserve(this->size() + std::distance(begin, end));
    }
    std::copy(begin, end, back_inserter_without_capacity_check<InIt>(*this);
}
```

Now, the other interesting bit is: Even if this is how it implemented, it doesn't really help you with respect to `std::copy()`! You cannot partially specialize `std::copy()` (well, you can't partially specialize any function template) and the type of target iterator is not defined (in the above implementation it would be a non-capacity checking variant of `std::back_inserter()` if `InIt` is a forward iterator and otherwise it would just be the same as `std::back_inserter()`.

Comment: Hm, but if the implementation were `using namespace std; ...; copy (begin, end, ...)`, then I could define `copy` for my iterator class (being first and second argument) in the iterator class's namespace, and my version of `copy` would be found by ADL. I really do not think the standard implementation of delegating to `append (const char *, size_type)` is a good idea, as it necessarily involves building a character array first.

Comment: I'm not claiming that it is a Good Idea at all. All I'm saying is that this is what the standard says and it implies that the implementation actually shall not call a vanilla, ADL-findable version of `copy()`. Also, if it found both your `copy()` specialized on the input iterators it could create an ambiguity with a version of `copy()` specialized on the output iterator. It seems more reasonable to stay out of this and not to consider `copy()` to be a customization point.

Answer (score 5):

The string class has its own traits class that defines the operations it can do on the characters it contains.

To copy `char`s, `basic_string<char>` will use `std::char_traits<char>::copy` (instead of the more general `std::copy`). That probably maps to the `memcpy` function in the standard C library.

Comment: There's no reason that there couldn't be an overload for `std::copy(const char*,const char*,char*)` to map to `memcpy` too.

Comment: There might very well be one, but `std::string` cannot use that (directly, at least), as it has to go through the `char_traits` class.

Comment: Actually, I can only see a direct reference to `traits::length()` when the `std::basic_string` class template needs to determine the length of a string pointed to by a `cT const*`, and `traits::eq()` and `traits::compare()` to compare character values. I don't see any requirement that `traits::copy()` needs to be called!

Comment: :-) Right, the `char_traits` defines functions needed by the `basic_string` template, but the standard doesn't say that those functions has to be used. Perhaps a slight oversight?